# Reading file in Python one line at a time

Tags: python, file-io

I do appreciate this question has been asked million of time, but I can't figure out while attempting to read a .txt file line by line I get the entire file read in one go.

This is my little snippet

```
    num = 0

with open(inStream, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        num += 1
        print line + " ..."
        print num
```

Having a look at the open function there is anything that suggest a second param to limit the reading as that is just the "mode" to pen the file.

So I can only guess there are same problem with my file, but this is a txt file, with entry line by line.

Any hint?

Comment: What Operating System do you run? Did you produce the TXT file using its native editor or by some other means? I suppose your line-ending convention is broken.

Comment: Your code _does_ read the file line by line. Is it possible that you're trying to read a text file with inappropriate line endings (Unix line endings on Windows, classic-Mac line endings on Unix/OS X, etc.)?

Comment: @Hyperboreus: How is that question relevant here?

Comment: As you can see [here](http://ideone.com/D45vEu), OP's program is correctly written.

Comment: @Hyperboreus: Well, his problem is that he's getting the whole file as the first line in a `for line in file` loop, and doesn't want to. A question about someone who _wants_ to get the whole file by explicitly calling `read` instead of looping and has run into some weird bug that he worked around with `mmap` isn't likely to help him.

Comment: can you show us the guts of the file inStream?

Comment: @abarnert Thanks for the amplification. I understood "I get the entire file read in one go" as "I get the entire file read into memory in one go" and not as "All lines of the file get printed as though they were only one.". Removed my misleading link.

Comment: Also, apologies if this sounds dumb, but… this is actually a text file, with meaningful "lines", not a big hunk of arbitrary binary where you're just hoping it'll break things down into reasonable-sized chunks, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without a little more information, it's hard to be absolutely sure… but most likely, your problem is inappropriate line endings.

---

For example, on a modern Mac OS X system, lines in text files end with `'\n'` newline characters. So, when you do `for line in f:`, Python breaks the text file on `'\n'` characters.

But on classic Mac OS 9, lines in text files ended with `'\r'` instead. If you have some ancient classic Mac text files lying around, and you give one to Python, it will go looking for `'\n'` characters and not find any, so it'll think the whole file is one giant line.

(Of course in real life, Windows is a problem more often than classic Mac OS, but I used this example because it's simpler.)

---

**Python 2**: Fortunately, Python has a feature called ["universal newlines"](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines). For full details, see the link, but the short version is that adding `"U"` onto the end of the mode when opening a text file means Python will read any of the three standard line-ending conventions (and give them to your code as Unix-style `'\n'`).

In other words, just change one line:

```
with open(inStream, "rU") as f:
```

**Python 3**: Universal newlines are part of the standard behavior; adding `"U"` has no effect and is deprecated.

Comment: Well I'm using Mac OS X 10.7.5, thanks for the fast response.

Comment: @AndreaMoro: I'm surprised that you'd have classic-Mac text files lying around. I don't have any on my MacBook. I did recently find a Jaz disk which is probably full of source code for MacOS 6 programs, but I'm not sure how you'd get the files off such a thing nowadays… Anyway, glad it helped.

Comment: I've created one file copy and pasting from some rows in Excel. Perhaps my fault? Or perhaps a problem with TextEdit that has been used for saving the file.

Comment: @AndreaMoro: TextEdit can creates "rich text files", usually saved as either `.rtf` files or `.rtfd` bundles, as well as plain text files. You can't process a RTF file as a plain text file. You will either need to use an RTF parser, or, more simply, just re-open the RTF file in TextEdit and use the "Make Plain Text" command (under the "Format" menu, in 10.8) and save it as a new text file.